# How Can I create a bootable USB for Ubuntu on Windows 10 from an iso image?

Tags: live-usb

I have downloaded the Ubuntu `.iso` and now I want to make a bootable USB from it on my Windows 10 system, can anyone help me, I am a noob at programming so I expect it to be explained in layman's terms. :)

Comment: Step 2: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and other programs for this. The two named programs feature an easy-to-use and self-explanatory GUI. There you select your USB drive and the ISO image and everything else is taken care of by the program.

Comment: Is it okay to use Rufus?

Comment: Sure. I never used it myself but it looks like it can do the job too.